# Not getting data with codeingiter api hitting with react js browser build fetch method

Tags: reactjs, api, codeigniter

I have created an API with Codeigniter , i test it with postman it is working fine there but when I am hitting it with react js the post data is not appearing on the server side

here is the react code

```js
 async function submitForm() {
    const response = await fetch(
        "url",
        {
            method: "POST", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
            body: JSON.stringify({
                first_name: enteredFirstName,
                last_name: enteredLastName,
                email: enteredEmail,
                company_name: enteredComapanyName,
                phone: enteredPhone,
                company_type: cType,
            }), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
        }
    );
    console.log(response.json());
}
```

here is the server-side Codeigniter code

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
print_r($_POST);

I am passing value from the client side but not getting it on the server side

I am getting an empty array

I am expecting an array of data I am passing from the client side
I tried almost all the headers but not getting any data
I think it might be a header issue because i am getting data in the firebase

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I am passing data with JSON and getting the data on the server side is form data that's why it was an empty array

this is how i get the json data

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```